How to suppress shell command output in Jenkins pipeline stage view
In Jenkins new version (e.g. 2.454+), stage view always print shell command itself.
For shell script, adding "set +x" to hide output in console. However, from stage view, click "Log", it show shell command itself.
how to hide output in stage view?

Is there any solution to implement it?
